# Print Chapter name in TOC but not where chapter starts

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titlesec

I want to use an image (in which chapter name is written) in place of where the chapter name is. But chapter name is required in TOC as text.

Following code give a blank page before the chapter title image.
Thanks for all the help :)
MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn,openany,twoside]{book}
%
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{TB_bookstyle}
%%%%%
%
\begin{document}
%
\newgeometry{textwidth=\paperwidth, textheight=\paperheight, noheadfoot, nomarginpar}
\chapter*{\tiny{\color{white}{Messages}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Messages}
%\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{./images/Chap_Msgs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Self Made style file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{TB_bookstyle}
%
%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS AND SETTINGS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
%\geometry{margin=1.5in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
\geometry{top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in}
% \geometry{landscape} % set up the page for landscape
%   read geometry.pdf for detailed page layout information
%
%%%%GRAPHICS, FLOATS, SYMBOLS AND MATHS
% support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{floatrow}%for side captions
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%for proper characters
% for rotating floats
\usepackage{lscape}
%for subfigures and tables
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\usepackage{longtable}%for long tables
%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%%
\usepackage[allcolors=black,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}%no boxes for links
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}%automatic table /figure before refs
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}%remove brackets around eq nos
%%%
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo} %for upright math
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wasysym} %for per mil sign
\usepackage{array} % for better arrays (eg matrices) in maths
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{enumitem}% very flexible & customisable lists (eg. enumerate/itemize, etc.)
\usepackage{verbatim} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % for upright CO2 etc
\usepackage{wrapfig}%text wrapped figures/tables
%%
\usepackage{calligra}%For cursive font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext, color}
\definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.5, 0.2, 0.0}
\definecolor{cornellred}{rgb}{0.7, 0.11, 0.11}
\definecolor{brown_w}{rgb}{0.65, 0.16, 0.16}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\chapter*}[hang]{\tiny\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{white}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\tiny\bfseries}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{} 
\titlespacing{\chapter}{-20pt}{-20pt}{-20pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}
%to stop starting new chapter in new page
\usepackage{atbegshi,etoolbox}
%%
%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
%\setlength{\headheight}{50pt} 
\pagestyle{empty} % options: empty , plain , fancy
%%
%%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Put the bibliography in the ToC
%%%%
%\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
%\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape} % No bold!
%\usepackage{tocloft} % Alter the style of the Table of Contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
%\usepackage{bibentry}%for no ref list
%made command
%\makeatletter
%\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
%%%%%%%
%
%\usepackage[colon,authoryear]{natbib}
%
%mytilde
\newcommand{\mytilde}{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\mathtt{\sim}$}}
%%%
```

Comment: Using your code, I only get a single page with an image on it, nothing more. I think the code doesn't really reproduce your problem.

Comment: Well, I ran this MWE again and every time I am getting two pages. One blank one not

Comment: I also get one page when running with `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` or without `[demo]` and with `\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image}`. However I do get two pages with `\includegraphics[height=50cm]{example-image}`. So that means that your image is too large to fit on the page and it is shifted to the next page. Try to make it smaller (e.g., `0.9\textwidth`).